# Is there a Chrome extension similar to Automatic Save Folder for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, automation, nas, google-chrome-extensions

[This extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4781) allows you to automatically download files with a certain extension to a NAS drive. This could be a torrent, for instance, where download and seeding is automated by the NAS itself, leaving me to go about my own business on my own computer.

Does anyone know a Chrome extensions that mirrors this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest equivalent extension I know of is [Download All](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dichiooocmfaijgfjjohpjdbelmficee).

However, Chrome API limitations cripple it badly.
The developer says in this support [question](http://groups.google.com/group/download-all-chrome/browse_thread/thread/576ae1c6b570c1f0):

> the reason that this extension doesn't
>   provide same functionality as in
>   Firefox is that simply there isn't
>   enough API for downloads. Chrome
>   extensions are less powerful than
>   Firefox ones and there is nothing I
>   can do with it, it's up to Google.
>
> Your files are downloaded to folder
>   where all downloads from Chrome are
>   saved - look at Chrome settings.

Your only other solution is to use an external third-party download manager, but this requires you to right-click on links in order to download.

Comment: Interesting—and disconcerting. I’ll just have to find away around it that doesn’t include Chrome. I think I already have a solution. Thanks for the elaborate and exhaustive answer.

Comment: Given that Firefox will be killing off its XUL extensions in favour of the Chrome APIs in Firefox 57, I've been looking for replacements and I thought I'd point out that you don't strictly *need* to right-click to use a download manager... you just need an extension that gets hacky with "what should I download?" detection and binds `onclick` in each page so that you can override the default left-click behaviour. Failing that, set up something which monitors your default download folder and then moves files to where they should actually go. (I'd suggest a tool, but I write my own for that.)

Answer (score 0):

probably not the solution you seek, but could be a workaround to what you need.

Could you use a software like [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) (for Mac) that automate files organization